# How can I fix this error? Javascript Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to make a logger in Javascript. Here's my code so far:

```js
var logs = document.getElementById("logs");
int idx = 0;
var auto_logger = logs.addEventListener('logger', function(event) {
  // now to walk the talk
  var localLogs = logs.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[0];
  if (localLogs.childNodes[idx] != null) {
    idx = idx + 1;
    console.log("log added!");
  };
});
```

For some reason it gives an error on line 2, which is `int idx = 0;`. I don't know how I can fix this. Can someone help?

Comment: in javascript, you declare variable using var idx = 0;

Comment: This is not C++... `int` doesn't exist. Just use `var`...

Comment: Thanks, sorry not used to js.

Comment: Use 'var' javascript will typecast automatically based value.